# Windows Azure caching cshtml files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm evaluating Windows Azure for an MVC application I'm working on.  I ported the app a little while ago and uploading without any issues.  I've come back about 4 weeks later to upload the next version and now I'm getting an exception being thrown.

Source: System.Web.WebPages
Message: Section not defined: "main".
Stack trace: at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSection(String name, Boolean required) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in e:\sitesroot\0\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:line 77 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass6.<>c*_DisplayClassb.b_*4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The only reason that I can think that this would happening is that either the _layout.cshtml file is not updating or the Home/Index.cshtml file is not updating.  The MVC application works correctly both running in the Windows Azure emulator or running stand alone in IIS.

I have completely deleted the role and redeployed as well as upgraded.  I have not configured CDN or the Azure Cache and I can confirm files that have been added to the project since the last successful deployment are available.

Right now I'm out of ideas...

EDIT:

I've narrowed the issue down to a call to Html.RenderAction in the sub layout.  I'm wondering if this is an issue of it being an MVC 4 project that I'm testing.  I have loaded the latest System.Web.Mvc dll as part of my project but whether there's an issue on the Azure servers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. The problem was that a partial view being returned through a RenderAction was failing. This was because the partial view included a select list that was populated by a database call and the connection to the database was failing.  The database on Azure is a SQL Azure database but locally it is just a SQL 2008 R2 database. I thought I had already tested the database connectivity to the SQL Azure but obviously not.

Thanks for your time Ming.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether you have @RenderSection("main") inside _layout.cshtml. If you have, please make sure every page that uses _layout.cshml has a section named main, not only Index.aspx. As you mentioned the project works fine locally, I would recommend you to make sure you’re deploying the latest version to the cloud. Please also try to rebuild the solution, delete the publish package, and package it again to see whether it helps.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't helped.

Comment: Since the issue cannot be reproduced on my side, could you please upload/share a test project on SkyDrive?  Actually, to troubleshoot this issue, we really need the source code to reproduce the problem, so that we can investigate the issue in house. It is not necessary that you send out the complete source of your project. We just need a simplest sample to reproduce the problem. You can remove any confidential information or business logic from it. Then we can find the issue more conveniently and provide further suggestions for you.